# Need to export multiple fields collections via views data export in XML

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting, entities

I have my site set up to import CSVs and manual entry and exporting the key information into an XML feed/File using views data export. 
I have a problem when I need to add a group of fields. The user can add as many of these groups of fields as they need and they should appear in the output in a single row as nested items.

When I use field collections the output produces invalid XML or is stripped of all wrappers so that it is just plain text. I have tried custom template files in my theme but views data export strips out the tags.

**Desired output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<file_information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<asset_data>
    <upn>GBHIS3473610HD30P001</upn>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <version>Sunday 26th January</version>
    <duration>00:00:30:00</duration>
    <tc_in>10:00:00:00</tc_in>
    <tc_out>10:00:30:00</tc_out>
    <aspect_ratio>16:9</aspect_ratio>
    <segment>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <tc_in>10.00.00.00</tc_in>
        <tc_out>10.00.30.00</tc_out>
    </segment>
    <segment>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
        <tc_in>DMC</tc_in>
        <tc_out>DMC</tc_out>
    </segment>
    <segment>
        <sequence>3</sequence>
        <tc_in>DMC</tc_in>
        <tc_out>DMC</tc_out>
    </segment>
    <segment>
        <sequence>4</sequence>
        <tc_in>DMC</tc_in>
        <tc_out>DMC</tc_out>
    </segment>
</asset_data>
</file_information>
```

**Actual output**
(rest of XML is fine)

```
<segment>
  <sequence>
    <section class="field field-name-field-sequence field-type-number-integer field-label-above view-mode-full">
     <h2 class="field-label">sequence:&amp;nbsp;</h2>
     <div class="field-items">
     <div class="field-item even">1</div>
     </div>
    </section>
  </sequence>
  <tc_in>
  <section class="field field-name-field-tc-in field-type-hms-field field-label-above view-mode-full">
     <h2 class="field-label">tc_in:&amp;nbsp;</h2>
     <div class="field-items">
       <div class="field-item even">
         <span class="hms hms-format-h-mm-ss">0:00:00</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </section>
  </tc_in>
  <tc_out>
    <section class="field field-name-field-tc-out field-type-hms-field field-label-above view-mode-full">
    <h2 class="field-label">tc_out:&amp;nbsp;</h2>
    <div class="field-items">
     <div class="field-item even">
       <span class="hms hms-format-h-mm-ss">0:00:30</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
  </tc_out> 
  <sequence>
    <section class="field field-name-field-sequence field-type-number-integer field-label-above view-mode-full">
     <h2 class="field-label">sequence:&amp;nbsp;</h2>
     <div class="field-items">
       <div class="field-item even">2</div>
     </div>
    </section>
   </sequence>
   <tc_in>
     <section class="field field-name-field-tc-in field-type-hms-field field-label-above view-mode-full">
     <h2 class="field-label">tc_in:&amp;nbsp;</h2>
     <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">
        <span class="hms hms-format-h-mm-ss">0:00:00</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
   </tc_in>
   <tc_out>
     <section class="field field-name-field-tc-out field-type-hms-field field-label-above view-mode-full">
     <h2 class="field-label">tc_out:&amp;nbsp;</h2>
     <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">
        <span class="hms hms-format-h-mm-ss">0:00:20</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
  </tc_out>
 </segment>
```

So how can I customise the output or should I use something other than field collections?

contents of my **field-collection-item.tpl.php**

```
<sequence><?php print render($content['field_sequence']); ?></sequence>
<tc_in><?php print render($content['field_tc_in']); ?></tc_in>
<tc_out><?php print render($content['field_tc_out']); ?></tc_out>
```

contents of my **views-data-export-xml-body.tpl.php**

```
<?php
   $item_item = 'asset_data';
?>
<?php foreach ($themed_rows as $count => $row): ?>
  <<?php print $item_item; ?>>
<?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
  <?php if($content != NULL){ ?>
    <?php $content = str_replace("&lt;","<",$content); 
     $content = str_replace("&gt;",">",$content); ?>
     <<?php print $xml_tag[$field]; ?>><?php print_r $content; ?></<?php print $xml_tag[$field]; ?>>
    <?php } ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
   </<?php print $item_item; ?>>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't cleaned tpl for rows and fields.

Comment: As far as I know, Field Collection's Views integration is poor, to say the least. @user24312 You might have better luck in the module issue queue.

Comment: @Mołot was right - I had cleaned fields tpl file but had a typo in the filename so it wasn't picking it up. Initial test looks good.

Comment: @user24312 feel free to post that as self-answer (if 8h limit for self-answers was lifted already).

Comment: G'dam typos always get you!

Comment: Still have a few hours to wait before I can self answer but have had time to test and needed to do another tweak to make it perfect so will include that when I reply.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Molot I needed to clean fields.tpl.php which I had done but had a typo in the name which is why I was puzzled.

In addition to this I needed to add some logic into views-data-export-xml-body.tpl.php to wrap each set of field items seperately.

(used str_replace to find the closing tag of the last element and insert the closing and opening wrapper tag)

```
$content = str_replace("/tc_out> <sequence>","/tc_out> </segment>
    <segment> <sequence>",$content);
```